# How to send Multiple decoded IR signals in one script

Tags: c++, ir

My final goal is to use my Arduino microcontroller as an "automatic remote". For now I would like to know how to send decoded NEC protocols one after another in a script.

I am using the Nano V 3.0 with a IR led I salvaged from an old remote. I used a VS838 and a 338R IR receiving module to decode the signals, both work 100%

I know how to send one protocol in a loop.

e.g

```
#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
}

void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        irsend.sendNEC(0x10676897, 32);
        delay(40);
    }
    delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst
}
```

I also know how to send the same protocol repetitively.

(Although it won't work in the loop I reckon it'll work in the final script)

e.g

```
#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
}

void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        irsend.sendNEC(0xFFFFFFFF, 32);
        delay(40);
    }
    delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst
}
```

However, I would like to include `106722DD`, `10676897` ,`10678877` and send them in one single C++ Script.

I was thinking something like calling each script through a loop might suffice but I have no idea how to do it in C++

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you are asking, so sorry if there is superfluous info in here.

Given that:

```
void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        irsend.sendNEC(0x10676897, 32);
        delay(40);
    }
    delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst
}
```

Sends a single command twice as one burst I think what you want to do is this:

```
void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        irsend.sendNEC(106722DD, 32);
        delay(40);
        irsend.sendNEC(10676897, 32);
        delay(40);
        irsend.sendNEC(10678877, 32);
        delay(40);
    }
    delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst
}
```

If that works it could be generalised into:

```
// New function to send 'items' codes which are held in the array 'data'
void sendMulti (const uint8_t& items, const uint32_t* data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        for (uint8_t itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < items; ++itemIndex)
        {
            irsend.sendNEC(data[itemIndex], 32);
            delay(40);
        }
    }
    delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst
}

void loop () {
    static const uint8_t MaxItems = 3;
    uint32_t  data[MaxItems] = {106722DD, 10676897, 10678877};

    sendMulti(MaxItems, data);
}
```

Then you could move onto reading the codes from serial or a network, etc.

Comment: Thanks it's working so far i'll post some updates as i progress.